# How to remove everything before : on every line?

Tags: text, notepad++

So basically i have text in format `something:something:something`
and i want to remove the first "something"+colon on every new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

Search: `^[^:]*:([^\n]*)`

Replace by: `\1`

Select: "Regular expressions"

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>